# SQL2012 proxy has no permissions to write to SSISDB

Tags: permissions, ssis

I have a package which runs under a service account which i have given proxy permissions to in SSIS Package Execution.  However, when it starts to run i get the following error

Cannot open database "SSISDB" requested by the login. The login failed.  Login failed for user 'ServiceAcountXXX'.

I am assuming that the service account has no access to the SSISDB database to record all that execution logging information.  I thought that giving it the SSIS Package Execution access would automatically do that.  Does anyone know what permissions I still need to give the service account so it will run ?  When i ran the sql agent this wasn't an issue.

Erick

Answer (score 7):

If I understand correctly, you've authorized a proxy to execute jobsteps of type SSIS. The remaining step, is to grand the credentials account for your proxy the `ssis_admin` role in the SSISDB catalog.